# Struggling with loops and statements

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

So I've almost finished a calculator but after giving the results, I want it to ask if I'm still gonna use it.
At the beginning of the code I have this loop to make it start again unless I typed 'n'.

```
# LOOP TO MAKE IT STAY ON
import sys
from colorama import init
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style
init()
while True:
```

Then the rest of the code which is finished goes on.

Then, at the end, I've tried this:

```
    answer = input()

        def badanswer():
            if answer != "y" or "n":
                return True
            else:
                return False

        while badanswer is True:
            print ("Wrong answer")
            answer = input(("Wanna keep using the calculator? y/n "))
            if badanswer is False:
                if answer == "y":
                    continue
                else:
                    break
                sys.exit()
```

Somehow when I test it I type a random letter (not y or n) and the program continues... What I am missing here? I'm pretty new to python so forgive my mistakes! Thanks.

Comment: The line `if badanswer is False:` isn't calling the `badanswer()` function: It's checking if the value `badanswer` (which *is itself a function*) is Truthy/Falsey. It will always be truthy.

Comment: I'm not sure if there are other problems, but that definitely stood out to me/

Comment: @anonymouscoward actually it is checking if the function object **is** the singleton `False` object

Comment: Ah, @juanpa.arrivillaga, you're totally right! In this case, the result is the same, but yes -- good catch!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem is the

```
if answer != "y" or "n":
```

"or" is a logical operator, and does not allow you to "double" a != comparison like you are trying to do. The actual meaning of this statement is `if answer is not "y", or if "n"`, and `"n"`, like any nonempty string, is always True in boolean context.

You want

```
if answer not in ("y", "n"):
```

You also need to actually call badanswer() by adding the parentheses.

There's also no reason to add the `if True` to the loop condition — `while badanswer()` does the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

`badanswer` is a function, not a boolean. You need to call the function and get its return value, like so: `if badanswer() is True`

However, your logic for exiting the program is needlessly contrived. You don't need the `badanswer` function at all. Just get the input from the user and check whether it is 'y' or 'n'.

```
while True: # loop for exit prompt
    answer = input("Wanna keep using the calculator? y/n ").lower()
    # using .lower() to permit 'Y' and 'N' as well

    if answer == "n":
        sys.exit()

    elif answer == "y":
        break 
        # exits from the 'exit prompt' loop,
        # returns to the outside calculator loop

    else:
        print("Bad answer!")
```

**Note:** As mentioned in the comments, `sys.exit()` is a pretty cutthroat way to exit your program. You can do it more gracefully by modifying a variable that is checked by the outer calculator loop; e.g., initialize a variable `keep_running = True`, run the main loop with `while keep_running: (...)` and if the user requests to exit from the calculator, set `keep_running = False` so that the main loop exits.

Comment: using `sys.exit()` is generally a really bad idea as it can make debugging a pain (imaging hitting that with a debugger). Instead, I would use a sentinel-value as `while` condition. Something like `while keep_running: ...` and then set this value to `False` in the loop

Comment: Good idea. I'll add a comment to the post.

Comment: I used sys.exit() cause I read it from some other topics in the forum, I had no idea about it. About the keep_running thing, I'm gonna add that for sure, haven't thinked in that! Thanks.